# Given time column, how can I create time bins in R?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

Given a dataframe with say 3 columns:

```
date       time    respond 
1/1/2018   15:40   1
4/5/2017   08:25   0
3/4/2016   09:00   1
5/4/2017   09:25   1

....
```

I want to bin my time column say into 24 bins - for each our and if for example I have 50 samples I want all times between hour1 to hour2 (08:00 - 09:00) to represent bin of 08:00 hour etc.

Now when I will achieve this, I want to count how many responders I have within each bin:

bin08:00 = 10 responders
bin09:00 = 134 responders

and to plot it using ggplot2.

Also please guide me how can I create different bin map:
from 08:00 to 12:00 AM - hourly bins.
12:00AM - 15:00 every 15 minutes bins etc.

Please guide me how can I do this.

@akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `strptime` to format your `time` column as POSIX objects, and then use `format` on those objects to round down to the hour like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df$hour <- format(strptime(df$time, "%H:%M"), "%H:00")

df %>% group_by(hour) %>% summarize(respond = sum(respond))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#    hour respond
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 08:00       0
# 2 09:00       2
# 3 15:00       1
```